# Loading cookies in JSON format into requests

Tags: python

I've got some cookies sent over from a client to allow me to log into his server programatically without needing the credentials.

I'm using the requests package to make HTTP requests to his server. The problem is the cookies he has sent are all in JSON format and I can't seem to find any way to load these cookies.

Aside from writing a method to convert them into regular cookies are there any existing solutions to load these cookies?

Here is my current code:

```
def cookieLogin(cookies):

    with open(cookies) as f:
        cookies = requests.utils.cookiejar_from_dict(json.load(f)[0] )

    session = requests.session()
    session.cookies = cookies

    r = session.get('https://example.com')
```

Cookie example:

```
[
{
    "domain": ".example.com",
    "hostOnly": false,
    "httpOnly": false,
    "name": "act",
    "path": "/",
    "sameSite": "no_restriction",
    "secure": false,
    "session": true,
    "storeId": "0",
    "value": "875",
    "id": 1
},
{
    "domain": ".example.com",
    "expirationDate": 1479135421.720188,
    "hostOnly": false,
    "httpOnly": false,
    "name": "c_user",
    "path": "/",
    "sameSite": "no_restriction",
    "secure": true,
    "session": false,
    "storeId": "0",
    "value": "109",
    "id": 2
},
...
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./cookieInviter.py", line 37, in <module>
    session = cookieLogin(args.cookies)
  File "/Users/jj/Projects/Jim/login.py", line 78, in cookieLogin
    r = session.get('https://example.com')

  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 487, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 461, in request
    prep = self.prepare_request(req)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 394, in prepare_request
    hooks=merge_hooks(request.hooks, self.hooks),
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 297, in prepare
    self.prepare_cookies(cookies)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 518, in prepare_cookies
    cookie_header = get_cookie_header(self._cookies, self)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests/cookies.py", line 136, in get_cookie_header
    jar.add_cookie_header(r)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/cookielib.py", line 1342, in add_cookie
_header
    attrs = self._cookie_attrs(cookies)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/cookielib.py", line 1301, in _cookie_at
trs
    self.non_word_re.search(cookie.value) and version > 0):
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

CookieJar:

```
<RequestsCookieJar[<Cookie domain=.example.com for />, <Cookie hostOnly=False for />, <Cookie httpOnly=False for />,
<Cookie id=1 for />, <Cookie name=act for />, <Cookie path=/ for />, <Cookie sameSite=no_restriction for />, <Cookie s
ecure=False for />, <Cookie session=True for />, <Cookie storeId=0 for />, <Cookie value=... for />]>
```

Answer (score 2):

One way is to create a function that turns all of a dictionaries non-string values into strings recursively

```
import requests


session = requests.session()


def stringify(obj: dict) -> dict:
    """turn every value in the dictionary to a string"""
    for k, v in obj.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            # if value is a dictionary, stringifiy recursively
            stringify(v)
            continue
        if not isinstance(v, str):
            if isinstance(v, bool):
                # False/True -> false/true
                obj[k] = str(v).lower()
            else:
                obj[k] = str(v)
    return obj


with open('cookies.json') as f:
    cookie_list: list = json.load(f)
    # create the cookie jar from the first cookie
    cookie_jar = requests.utils.cookiejar_from_dict(stringify(cookie_list[0]))
    # append the rest of the cookies
    for cookie in cookie_list[1:]:
        requests.utils.add_dict_to_cookiejar(cookie_jar, stringify(cookie))
    session.cookies = cookie_jar
```

Answer (score -3):

Use [requests.utils.cookiejar_from_dict(cookie_dict)](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#requests.utils.cookiejar_from_dict) to create a cookie jar from a dict:

```
jar = requests.utils.cookiejar_from_dict(cookie_dict)
session = request.Session()
session.cookies = jar
r = session.get(url)
```

Comment: I'm already doing that, it complains about the JSON characters `[` and `{`

Comment: If the file contains valid JSON, you should use `json.load(f)`, pickle is used to store python objects but is not the same format.

Comment: Still no joy. I need to set the cookies for the session. `requests.session(cookies=cj)` doesn't work. Apparently `session()` takes no arguments.

Comment: You can create the session object and then set the ´cookies´ attribute on it, i updated my answer with some example code.

Comment: Python is complaining that the boolean and int values are not strings. You can either surround all non-string values in your original file with double quotes, or cast them to string in your code (the docs for the json module can be of help: https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/json.html )

Comment: `cookiejar_from_dict()` can only handle simple key-value pairs, e.g. `{"foo": "bar"}` and can't handle full cookie objects.